# Using ImageData object in drawImage

Tags: javascript, putimagedata

Is it possible to use `ImageData` array object to get an Image() object. My eventual goal is to use `drawImage` instead of `putImageData` since `putImageData` is too slow (from stackoverflow similar qs and my own tests). All I have is `ImageData` array that I want to draw on top of an existing image on a canvas .

Answer (score 8):

You can create an `ImageBitmap` from an `ImageData` and pass that to `drawImage()`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap

Something like:

```
const imgdata = ...;
const ctx = ...;

createImageBitmap(imgdata).then(function(imgBitmap) {
    ctx.drawImage(imgBitmap, ...remaining args);
});
```

I was able to do this to scale some `ImageData` I had, since `putImageData` does not have arguments for scaling. Unfortunately, it looks like IE, Edge, and Safari do not support `createImageBitmap()`.

It's worth mentioning that for my case (resizing the `ImageData`), `createImageBitmap()` does have extra options for resizing the resulting `ImageBitmap` on its own.

Comment: You can use one of:
`function createImageBitmap(image: ImageBitmapSource): Promise<ImageBitmap>;`, `function createImageBitmap(image: ImageBitmapSource, sx: number, sy: number, sw: number, sh: number): Promise<ImageBitmap>;`

Comment: does createImageBitmap() copy pixel data or just make a reference?

Comment: I think generally anything that's an ImageBitmapSource is immutable, so it's probably taking a reference?

Comment: but is it faster than putImageData? @wolf1oo

Comment: This is not supported in neither the latest Safari nor older Edge, so you will need to polyfill it to support those browsers. Google "safari createImageBitmap polyfill"